# ProgressDialog doesn't show just flashes

Tags: android

I have time consuming function upload /* around 10 sec  */. I am trying before start upload to show ProgressDialog and when upload finishes to dismiss ProgressDialog and I trying like

```
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(Uploader.this,
                "Connecting...", "Uploading",
                true, false);
        Uploader.this
        .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                upload();
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

            }
        });
```

Problem is that Progress doesn't show for around 10s, only flashes, like it first upload and then call show and dismiss ( I tried to put show above thread, but it is the same ).
What to do ? ( Upload is void function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're upload code should not run on the UI thread.  If it does, then it will block that thread from doing anything else, such as displaying a progress dialog.  Save your progress dialog, show it, spawn a new thread to do the upload, and when the upload is complete, use a Handler to get back to the UI thread and close the progress dialog

Comment: +1 - agree. @Damir You should use `AsyncTask` for painless threading.

Comment: @Adil Soomro Can you help me with AsyncTask, what to put in <> when update is void and no need parameters?

Comment: use `AsynTask<Void, Void, Void>` and have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702695/android-async-task-progressdialog-isnt-showing-until-background-thread-finishes)

Comment: I'm using an `AsyncTask` and on `onPreExecute` I create a `ProgressDialog` and on `onPostExecute` I dismiss it. But I have the same problem too. What could be wrong? The only thing is that in `doInBackground` override, I connect to an HTTP service.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you perform upload operation, instead of another thread, on UI thread, which is currently trying to execute progress dialog?