# Does progressDialog have a minimum time?

Tags: android, mysql, progressdialog

Hi I'm trying out using a progress dialog while I'm connecting to mysql database on a distance server, usually it takes about 1 second (approximatively) to register/create an account but I wanted to be sure I wasn't going to freeze the app ... So i've put a progressdialog and since the treatement are very fast I guess it doesn't show up ? Is that right ? Is there a minimum time for it to show up ?

Comment: Maybe it is just disappearing extremely fast. This should help you show it for a minimum time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540854/progressdialog-only-shows-for-an-instant

Answer (score 0):

You can start a processDialog in a thread.

```
private ProgressDialog progDialog;
String str_process = getResources().getString(R.string.str_process);  
String str_wait = getResources().getString(R.string.str_wait);  
progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyApp.this, str_process, str_wait);  
new Thread() {  
    public void run() {  
        try{
            //TOTO here, put your code here or sleep few seconds
        }catch (Exception e){ }
     handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
     progDialog.dismiss();
     }
 }.start();

private Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override  
    public void handleMessage(Message msg){

    }
};
```

May be help you.