# Showing alert dialog with yes and no button and function on it

Tags: android, android-asynctask

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android ASync task ProgressDialog isn't showing until background thread finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702695/android-async-task-progressdialog-isnt-showing-until-background-thread-finishes)

I am implementating an android app. I have following Activity
1.StartMenu:-In This Activity there is three button when i press Start. it moves on Another Activity AndroidGame. in Androidgame There is context of Main game panel.so it start executing game. I want that when maingamepanel loads it show a progressDilog .after selecting yes it should start game.I am unable to progress dialog. please suggest where should progressDialog kept?
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);

```
    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Trial Period has Expired.");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Ok",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {



                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Can you post the AsynTask code from your project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478517/how-to-display-a-yes-no-dialog-box-in-android

Answer (score 0):

After Clicking the button in alert dialog it starts another activity.
There in onCreate() method write the following:

```
    doback dob=new doback();
    dob.execute();
```

below the oncreate()

```
    class doback extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>
 {

  protected Long doInBackground(URL... arg0) 
  {

  }
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
  {

  }
  protected void onPostExecute(Long result) 
  {
   try
   {
    dialog.dismiss();
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
    e.printStackTrace();
    dialog.dismiss();
   }
  }
 }
```